# Jasmine marble testing observable with ngIf async pipe

Tags: angular, angular-test, jasmine-marbles

I want to test an `Observable` with jasmine-marble testing, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to trigger change detection for `ngIf`, which should render the component.

This is a simplified version of my class:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  data$: Observable<{data: any[]}>;

  constructor(private baseService: BaseService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data$ = this.baseService.get(endpoint);
  }
}
```

And my html file:

```html
<custom-component *ngIf="data$ | async as value" [data]="value.data">
    ...
</custom-component>
```

This is my current test, which fails:

```js
it ('should display custom component', fakeAsync(() => {
    const expected = cold('a|',  {a: {data: [{id: 1}]}});
    baseServiceStub.get.and.returnValue(expected);
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(component.data$).toBeObservable(expected); // this passes and the observable also holds the correct value
    expect(baseService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(endpoint); // this passes aswell
    component.data$.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val); // here I can log the correct value of the observable ( {data: [{id:1}]})
    });
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('custom-component'))).not.toBeNull(); // this fails
}));
```

Unfortunately everything I got is this

```
Error: Expected null not to be null.
```

There's no issue with the service or the observable itself, but it seems to me that for some reason the DOM doesn't trigger change detection with the async pipe which would render the component.

PS: When I am using `getTestScheduler().flush()` I get the error `Can't subscribe to undefined` instead.

Comment: Please add a stackblitz example, you say there's no problem with the service nor the observable. However, I don't trust your words :)

Comment: shouldn't it be ? `baseServiceStub.get.and.returnValue(of({data: [{id: 1}]}));` of from rxjs?

Comment: This is my current StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-phifhp?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts . For some reason StackOverflow didn't let me edit my post because of an formatting issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating another test suite, where I defined a value for the observable manually. I'm not entirely happy with this approach but it is a workaround for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your subscribe is async. That means your `console.log` can fire after your last `expect`. At your last expect the data probably has not loaded yet so the value is undefined.

Using `tick(100)` instead of `tick()` will probably work. Note this will make your test 100ms slower.

You could also switch to async and wait for the observable to return a value:

```js
it ('should display custom component', async(() => {
    ...
    // tick(); //dont call this
    ...
    await component.data$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise()
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('custom-component'))).not.toBeNull(); 
}));
```

Comment: I am not quite getting the result I would like to see, even though I understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you by chance edit my StackBlitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-cnykr4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts