# Use jasmine marble testing for ngIf with async pipes (ColdObservable vs Observable)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine-marbles, async-pipe

### The problem

I'm trying to find a way of using marble testing to test side efects with async pipes. I've created a simple POC in Stackblitz so you may test it for yourselves
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzbtqx?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts

I'm using the result from a service method, which returns an `Observable` of either an object or null (see component file), and the `*ngIf` *directive* with an `async` *pipe* to either display or hide some html element depending wether the result from the method was an object or null (see html file).

Now I would like to create a *Unit Test* for the aforementioned case using *marble testing* however when I use the `cold` observable as the return value from my mocked service. It is allways being interpreted as null (or to be more exact *falsy*) by the `async` *pipe*.

##### html

```html
<h1>Marble Tests POC</h1>

<div id="conditional" *ngIf="value$ | async">
  <p>My Conditional message!</p>
</div>
```

##### component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  value$: Observable<{} | null>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.value$ = this.myService.getValue(false);
  }
}
```

##### spec

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  let mockedMyService = new MyServiceMock();
  let getValueSpy: jasmine.Spy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    getValueSpy = spyOn(mockedMyService, 'getValue').and.returnValue(of({}));
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // module definition providers and declarations...
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    // fixture and component initialization...
  });

  it('should display message when service returns different than null', () => {
    const testCase$ = cold('a', { a: {} });

    // if you comment the following line or use a normal Observable [of({})] instead of the 
    // coldObservable the test passes without issues.
    getValueSpy.and.returnValue(testCase$); 
    component.ngOnInit();

    getTestScheduler().flush();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const conditionalComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css('#conditional')
    );

    expect(conditionalComponent).not.toBeNull(); // Expected null not to be null.
  });
});
```

### Possible explanation:

I'm thinking the issue is that the `async` *pipe* seems not to work with `ColdObservable`s at all or at least it seems to be working in a different way than with normal `Observable`s. Now I know this can be tested without marble testing; that is the old way with `fakeAsync`  or `done` function, but I would love to use marble testing since is way simpler to reason about.

### Background

I came up with this idea from the example given on the [*Angular - Component testing scenarios*](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-marble-tests) documentation which gives the following testCase with *jasmine-marbles*:

```
it('should show quote after getQuote (marbles)', () => {
  // observable test quote value and complete(), after delay
  const q$ = cold('---x|', { x: testQuote });
  getQuoteSpy.and.returnValue( q$ );

  fixture.detectChanges(); // ngOnInit()
  expect(quoteEl.textContent)
    .withContext('should show placeholder')
    .toBe('...');

  getTestScheduler().flush(); // flush the observables

  fixture.detectChanges(); // update view

  expect(quoteEl.textContent)
    .withContext('should show quote')
    .toBe(testQuote);
  expect(errorMessage())
    .withContext('should not show error')
    .toBeNull();
});
```

As you can see. they use the `flush()` method to *run* the `coldObservable` and then use the `detectChanges()` method to update the view.

### P.S.

Before someone links [Jasmine marble testing observable with ngIf async pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67000075/jasmine-marble-testing-observable-with-ngif-async-pipe) as duplicate please note that question does not have a good answer and the OP did not post a comprehensive solution to his problem

Comment: Try detecting changes also just after the `ngOnInit` call so the `async` pipe subscribes to the new `value$` observable before the `flushing`.

Comment: That was it! 

Indeed we needed to detect changes right after the `ngOnInit` call and what's more it makes total sense since we are changing the observable that we are subscribing to.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [akotech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17614661/akotech) for the answer I'm providing bellow!

### Solution:

```
it('should display message when service returns different than null', () => {
  const testCase$ = cold('a-b-a', { a: {}, b: null });

  getValueSpy.and.returnValue(testCase$);

  component.ngOnInit();
  // Add the following detectChanges so the view is updated and the async pipe 
  // subscribes to the new observable returned above
  fixture.detectChanges();

  getTestScheduler().flush();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const conditionalComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(
    By.css('#conditional')
  );

  expect(conditionalComponent).not.toBeNull();
});
```

### Explanation:

We are modifying the returned `Observable` from the mocked service.

In the `beforeEach` *callback* we are returning an `Observable` from the `of` *operator* (we will call this `Obs1`). Then we are modifying this return value on the actual test returning now the `TestColdObservable` (we shall call this `Obs2`).

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  getValueSpy = spyOn(mockedMyService, 'getValue').and.returnValue(of({}));
  //                                                             --^-- 
  //                                                              Obs1
});

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  // ...
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

// ...

it('should display message when service returns different than null', () => {
  const testCase$ = cold('a', { a: {} }); // Obs2 definition

  getValueSpy.and.returnValue(testCase$);
  //                            --^--
  //                             Obs2
  component.ngOnInit();

  getTestScheduler().flush(); // We flush instead of update the async pipe's subscription
  // ...
}
```

We know that the first thing to be executed before our tests is the `beforeEach` *callback* and in case of multiple *callbacks* they are executed in order. So first we set the *mock* to return `Obs1` then we call `createComponent()` and `detectChanges()` which in turn invokes `ngOnInit()` and refreshes the view respectively. When the view is refreshed the `async` *pipe* subscribes to the `Obs1` returned by the *mock*.

After executing the `beforeEach` *callback*. We start executing the actual test and the first thing we do is modify the returned value of the *mock* to now return `Obs2`. Then we call the `ngOnInit` method to change the *observable* `value$` so it points to `Obs2`. However, instead of updating the view so the `async` *pipe* updates it's subscription to `Obs2`. We proceeded to `flush` the *observables* leaving the `async` *pipe* pointing to `Obs1` rather than `Obs2`;

##### Diagram:

###### Original

```
   [value$] ------------(Obs1)--------------------------------------(Obs2)------|------------------------------------------------
[asyncPipe] -----------------------------(Obs1)---------------------------------|-(we subscribe to an already flushed observable)
            ^              ^                ^              ^           ^        ^               ^
       returnValue  createComponent  detectChanges    returnValue   ngOnInit |flush!|      detectChanges
         (Obs1)        (ngOnInit)                        (Obs2)                       
       beforeEach      beforeEach2----------------------- test ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

###### Fixed

```
   [value$] ------------(Obs1)------------------------------------(Obs2)----------------------|----------------------
[asyncPipe] -----------------------------(Obs1)------------------------(We subscribe first)---|--------(Obs2)--------
            |              |                |            |           |        (Obs2)          |           |
            ^              ^                ^            ^           ^           ^            ^           ^
       returnValue  createComponent  detectChanges  returnValue   ngOnInit  detectChanges  |flush!|  detectChanges
         (Obs1)        (ngOnInit)                      (Obs2)                       
       beforeEach      beforeEach2--------------------- test --------------------------------------------------------
```